# Magento2 All Child product Out Stock display price

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

If all Simple options of a product are out of stock in a Configurable product then its not showing price but I want to show it. How do I do that?

Comment: On which page you want this? Can you please share any screenshot?

Comment: detail and list page